# 'ASIFormDataRequest.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm trying to use ASIFormDataRequest to send post request. But when I import the file

## import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

i'm getting error 'ASIFormDataRequest.h' file not found. Do I need to add any frame work to my project. I'm using Xcode 4.2 and I'm targeting iOS 5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you copied all ASIHTTPRequest files to your project? Give this a shot: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Comment: I added the framework that s mentioned on the link. but still no luck :(

Comment: Did you check "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" when adding the ASIHTTPRequest files? If not: Try to reimport the files and check this option. Maybe you just added them as a reference and deleted them later, so Xcode can't find them now …

Comment: Sorry, but where could I find this option. Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" ? i didn't find it.

Comment: Just drag & drop the files into your project – then Xcode will ask you if you really want to add the files and you can check this option.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried that but still no luck. I'm new to iOS programming, I'm not sure if ASIHTTPRequest.h is already available as framework from Apple in Xcode, or I have to download it from somewhere?

Comment: You have to download it. Try this Link: http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tarball/master After you downloaded and extracted it, you can import the files and start using ASIHTTP.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - If you are targeting iOS 5 and using ARC, you will also need to set a few compiler flags to turn ARC off for some of the ASIHttpRequest libraries.